# How to scale machine learning micro-service in Microsoft kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, devops

I want to automatically scale AI micro-service on kubernetes on number of request pending in queue and after completion task in queue pods automatically destroy.

Comment: Could you provide any details on your deployment (use case, .yaml files)? What k8s version are you using, are you using bare-metal server or some cloud provider?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 main ways to autoscale in Kubernetes, you can read about them here:

1. [Kubernetes autoscaling, explained](https://enterprisersproject.com/article/2021/3/kubernetes-autoscaling-explanation)
2. [Kubernetes Autoscaling: 3 Methods and How to Make Them Great](https://spot.io/resources/kubernetes-autoscaling-3-methods-and-how-to-make-them-great/)
3. [Kubernetes Autoscaling in Production: Best Practices for Cluster Autoscaler, HPA and VPA](https://www.replex.io/blog/kubernetes-in-production-best-practices-for-cluster-autoscaler-hpa-and-vpa)